# SQL query that returns value based on lookup of id in another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

```
    dbo.Events

    EventID               EventName            Location
    1                     Birthday Party       2
    2                     Wedding              1

    dbo.EventsLocation

    Location    LocationName
    1           Room 1
    2           Room 2
```

I would like to make an SQL query that returns the following

```
    Birthday Party    Room 2
    Wedding           Room 1
```

Comment: Since it looks rather like homework, a first suggestion might be to google for "sql join".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Events.EventName AS EventName,
  EventsLocation.LocationName AS LocationName
FROM
  Events
  INNER JOIN EventsLocation ON Events.Location=EventsLocation.Location
(WHERE ...)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the tables:

```
select e.EventName, l.LocationName
from Events e
inner join EventsLocation l on l.Location = e.Location
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select e.eventname, l.locationname
From events e
Left join eventslocation l
On e.location = l.location
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
      e.eventName,
      el.locationName
   from
      Events e
         join EventsLocation el
            on e.location = el.location
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT E.EventName,EL.LocationName 
FROM dbo.Events E 
INNER JOIN EventsLocation EL
ON E.Location=EL.Location
```