# SQL query that returns values based on lookups of id in another table - with nullable values

Tags: sql, inner-join

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735676/sql-query-that-returns-value-based-on-lookup-of-id-in-another-table) which is very similar, but mine goes a little further. I'm going to use his example but expand it a little more. Basically I'm adding another column for

I have 2 tables:

```
  dbo.Events
    ID               StartingLocation            EndingLocation
    1                     1                           null
    2                     2                           1

  dbo.EventsLocation
    ID    LocationName
    1           Room 1
    2           Room 2
```

What I want to do is write a query that will give me a result that looks like this:

```
ID     StartingLocation   EndingLocation
1           Room 1            null
2           Room 2            Room 1
```

I know I need to do some type of (inner?) join. But I'm getting stuck on the fact that I need to insert the data into *two* columns, and the fact that a value in EndingLocation can be null.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT Events.id AS EventID, EventsLocation.LocationName AS StartLocation, EventsLocation.LocationName AS EndLocation
FROM Events
INNER JOIN EventsLocation
on Events.StartingLocation=EventsLocation.id 
AND Events.EndingLocation=EventsLocation.id
```

but this gives me no results. If I chop off the `AND` condition, I get the following table that just repeats the StartingLocation twice.

```
EventID    StartLocation     EndLocation
1          Room 1            Room 1
2          Room 2            Room 2
```

Can anyone help me get on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want *two* joins.  Just in case one of the columns is `NULL`, I recommend `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT e.id AS EventID, else.LocationName AS StartLocation, ele.LocationName AS EndLocation
FROM Events e LEFT JOIN
     EventsLocation els
     ON e.StartingLocation = els.id LEFT JOIN
     EventsLocation ele
     ON e.EndingLocation = ele.id;
```